# Update Single Field of Hash in Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

Is it possible to update single field of Student object without needing other ones? Lets say I want to update grade field.

```
import com.ahmetk.redis.redishll.model.Student;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String> {}


@RedisHash("Student")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student implements Serializable {

   public enum Gender {
      MALE, FEMALE
   }

   private String id;
   private String name;
   private Gender gender;
   private int grade;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Student{" + "id='" + id + '\'' + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", gender=" + gender + ", grade=" + grade + '}';
   }
}



    @Test
    public void whenDeletingStudent_thenNotAvailableOnRetrieval() throws Exception {
        final Student student = new Student("Eng2015001", "John Doe", Student.Gender.MALE, 1);
        studentRepository.save(student);
        studentRepository.delete(student.getId());
        final Student retrievedStudent = studentRepository.findOne(student.getId());
        assertNull(retrievedStudent);
    }
```

Comment: Partial updates not helped much and example in docs is somewhat flawed for cases where entity saved and retrieved via repository. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61724152/3441253) answer for actual solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.partial-updates

the template in the example in the docs is an instance of RedisKeyValueTemplate

```
@Autowired
private RedisKeyValueTemplate redisKVTemplate;
redisKVTemplate.update(entity)
```